# Table name as Variable in Model Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Is it possible that i can pass some variable to the model in table name?**

I have a module that creates Customers.
Now for each Customers we create a separate table.
The Customers has a login and logout credentials.

Now for whenever a customer is created i can't always create a new model and pass it name there.

So i want that it gets dynamically, I am not sure how i can do it.

For each customer there will be one separate table.

Now i want to create a model for login, but what should i pass in the table name,it should be dynamic right?

**What should be the mysql schema to get this done?**

This my sample Model code:

```
    class Customer_User_M extends MY_Model

{

    protected $_table_name = 'customer1';
    protected $_order_by = 'name';


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct()
    }

}
```

The Customer Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer1` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `site_key` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `display_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `ext` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    `auth_user` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `base_ini_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `comments` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `custom_ini_filename` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Comment: what should be the attributes of your dynamic table?

Comment: @SubrataDeyPappu i have added the schema of my customer table

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it this way? Don't you rather want to create a general table for all customers with foreign key customer_id?

Comment: As per our requirement i have to do this, i hope i can find solution in this wya

Comment: so how you want to name your new tables... ?

Comment: They would be the names of company

Comment: then simply pass the company name as suffix of the table name while creating table in the model function... what is the problem?

Comment: So that should be with a variable right? and how will i be doing it?

Comment: what is your codeigniter version... I am trying to create a function for your need...

Comment: My codeigniter version is 2.6

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make a function in the model and put the code of create table in the function and pass dynamic table name in the function from controller like below....

Model function code:

```
function access_customer_table($table_name)
{
        //put ur select query here with table name in FROM clause will be     $table_name
}
```

and call this model function in your controller after load the model... and put your table name as argument...
like :

```
$this->load->model('Customer_User_M');
$this->Customer_User_M->access_customer_table('new_customer_table_name');
```

Please correct syntax if needed.. let me know if anything wrong in the logic...

Comment: this will create new tables right? but what if we have existing tables for customers?

Comment: $this->dbforge->create_table($table_name, TRUE);
        gives CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name ... so it will not create table if the table is already exist...

Comment: yes exactly but the tables are created from other module,  i have to just access its database and fetch records as per the table name in arugument

Comment: so just pass the table name and fetch record from the already created table... by select query... just need to pass the table name as a argument from controller for a function in model for fetch records of the table...

Comment: i have put up my model code so what do u suggest how should i do it here

Comment: create a function in your model with an argument as table name and call that function from controller... as i had edited in my answer above...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104530/discussion-between-ashish-raj-and-rajan).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to set the table name after loading the model. Just worked for me.

```
$this->load->model('customer_model','customer');
```

then,

```
$customer->table_name = "customer_xxx";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to save common customer details in a **customer** table and create another tables to store different data of customers with different fields having foreign key customerid.

Here, if you want to pass **dynamic tablename** to model then you need to **predefine all table names as an associative array** with **key-value pair**.Then you can pass **desired key-value** to model.It can be implemented using a **library**.So that you can use it all your **controllers**.